# Unable to pass form values using POST method

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass multiple values from the input form (checkboxes) with POST method, but only one of values is dumping, no matter how many checkboxes are checked.. What am i doing wrong?

var_dump($_POST);

result is : array(2) { ["pal_num"]=> string(1) "2" ["post"]=> string(3) "Go!" }

Code:

```
<?php
$l = $_POST['LT'];
$pals = '';

$r = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT pal_num FROM pl_tab WHERE lt_num='$l'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
    $pals .= '<input type="checkbox" name="pal_num" value="'.$row['pal_num'].'">'.$row['pal_num'].'<br>';
}

if($pal == '')
    echo '';
else
echo '<form name="get_pal" action="post.php" method="POST">';
echo $pals;
echo '<input type="submit" name="post" value="Go!">';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: Before asking a question here.. first search for answer on net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [post an array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#96902) (note the square brackets after `pal_num`:

```
$pals .= '<input type="checkbox" name="pal_num[]" value="'.$row['pal_num'].'">'.$row['pal_num'].'<br>';
```

Also, your `if` construct is incorrect, you should use brackets:

```
if($pal == '') {
    echo '';
} else {
    echo '<form name="get_pal" action="post.php" method="POST">';
    echo $pals;
    echo '<input type="submit" name="post" value="Go!">';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the the checkbox as an array  change the name to pal_num[]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST)
array(2) { ["pal_num"]=> string(1) "2" ["post"]=> string(3) "Go!" }

<?php
$l = $_POST['LT'];
$pals = '';

$r = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT pal_num FROM pl_tab WHERE lt_num='$l'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
    $pals .= '<input type="checkbox" name="pal_num[]" value="'.$row['pal_num'].'">'.$row['pal_num'].'<br>';
}

if($pal == '')
    echo '';
else
echo '<form name="get_pal" action="post.php" method="POST">';
echo $pals;
echo '<input type="submit" name="post" value="Go!">';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

use this code